# "1366 Incorrect string value" after trim("\u{200d}") on string

Tags: php

I'm currently pulling some data from an api.
I don't have any control over the data but on some strings it has white spaces on others it had some other characters I needed removed.  I fixed this by doing

```
trim($firstLineText, "\u{200d} \t\n\r\0\x0B")
```

The above makes sure the string is correct.  However now I can't insert this into an sql database.  I get this error:

```
1366 Incorrect string value: '\x9CJD\xE2\x80\x9D' for column
```

the field is set to varchar.  From my understanding Trim should just do that trim these characters is it adding something else that is now causing this?

EDIT: The original problem I had was that one of the strings was
this "e2808d20202020202020202020202020204c4c43" when I check it in string it reveals this "â LLC" .

Comment: Show hex for the original string and after trimming.

Comment: `trim` only works on bytes. And `\u{200d}` resolves to `\xe2` `\x80` `\x8d`, might corrupt following UTF-8 encodes.

Comment: This "e2808d20202020202020202020202020204c4c43" when I check it in string it reveals this "â LLC" .  I posted this question earlier and the answer I got was to Trim it I didn't realize it would cause a problem . @zerkms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mario correctly stated in the comments, `trim` only works on byte level and not unicode characters.

The unicode char "\u{200d}" expands into three bytes: 0xE2 0x80 0x8B

so

```
trim($firstLineText, "\u{200d}")
```

can be read as

```
trim($firstLineText, "\xE2\x80\x8B")
```

This is why you end up with the corrupted UTF-8 string.

To solve this, you might use

```
preg_replace("/(^[\x{200d} \t\n\r\x0B]+|[\x{200d} \t\n\r\x0B]+$)/u", "", $str);
```

But be aware that you might want to extend the list, because there are a lot more unicode whitespace characters!

Comment: Will this only work on the specific scenario?  I ran it and got this error: preg_replace(): Null byte in regex . @Kaii

Comment: @FabricioG i didn't test this and just copied your list... thinking about it, the null byte can never occur in the string you received and its safe to simply remove it from from the replacement. (see update)

Comment: Ran it again and got this:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 8 @Kaii, any ideas?

Comment: @FabricioG sorry i forgot to enable unicode mode in regex (`/.../u`) see update

Comment: Don't let it happen again... hahaha just kidding, THANK YOU BRO you helped me so much!  @Kaii

Comment: Actually is there anyway to make it so it only does it to front and end of string?  Currently it removes the space from anywhere in the string.  That's why I originally was using Trim.  Sorry didn't say this.  @Kaii

Comment: @FabricioG yes, see update. Now the regular expression got a little more complex using a capture group and the anchors `^` ( beginning) and `$` (end of string)